# Consistency of differentiable functions on a closed subset.

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question about differentiable functions.

Let $U \neq \emptyset$ be a open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $F$ be a closure of $U$.

I want to define the space of infinitely differentiable on $F$ denoted by $C^{\infty}(F)$.
\begin{align*}
A&:=C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{d})|_{F}\\
B&:=\{f \in \mathbb{R}^{F}:f|_{U} \in C^{\infty}(U),f|_{U}{\rm\,have\,continuous \,extension\,to\,}\partial U \}
\end{align*}
Can I prove $A=B$ ? I think $A \subset B$ is clear.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly $A\subset B.$ To see $A$ can be a proper subset of $B,$ take $U=(0,1),F=[0,1].$ Then $f(x) = x\sin (1/x)$ is $C^\infty$ on $(0,1)$ and continuous on $[0,1].$ So $f\in B.$ But $f'$ is unbounded on $(0,1),$ hence $f\not \in A.$

I would guess that $A$ is always a proper subset of $B.$

To have any chance for $A=B$ we should at the very minimum define $B$ to be the $C^\infty$ functions $f$ on $U$ such that all derivatives of $f$ extend to be continuous on $F.$

You might want to check out the Whitney extension theorem.

Comment: You mean $B$ should be $C^\infty$ functions of $U$ such all derivatives extend continuously on $F$, right?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I edited it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check up about Whitney extension theorem.